# android min sdk bug?

Tags: android

i have a nexus one with firmware 2.2 = sdk 8

when i dont use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

the app works just fine.
But when I add this (and as my device is 2.2 = sdk 8, so it should be same)
my imagepositions are wrong and the app totaly slow down ?

How do I set the minSDk right?

thx
chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer direct from the android forum

```
   <supports-screens 
 android:anyDensity="false" 
 android:normalScreens="true" 
 android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:smallScreens="true" 
 android:resizeable="true">
 </supports-screens>
```

in the manifest fix this circumstance.

chris

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Eclipse you might have choosen lower API version on project properties -> Android.